# JPA EJB PersistenceContext not injecting EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm using Wildfly 9.0.1 Final with a working JNDI data source. I've set up all my entities, but I can't seem to get it working. I'm trying to inject the EntityManager using the PersistenceContext, but it doesn't seem to be working, and it's throwing a null pointer exception:

*persistence.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/jdbc/ds</jta-data-source>
        <class>EventEntity</class>
        <class>EventDaoImpl</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

EventEntity is the Entity, and EventDaoImpl is the class which handles basic CRUD operations on it:

```
@Stateless
public class EventDaoImpl {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<EventEntity> getEvents() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e from EventEntity AS e");
        return q.getResultList();
    }
}
```

It may be worth mentioning that the JPA and the DaoImpl are in one maven module, while I'm trying to access it from another module. The dependencies are correct. I'm testing this in another class with the following code:

```
EventDaoImpl edi = new EventDaoImpl();
List<EventEntity> events = edi.getEvents();
```

I tried specifying the provider the the persistence.xml file, like this:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

but my IDE says it can't resolve anything past the `org.hibernate`, which is strange, since I do have a maven dependency set on hibernate in the jpa pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which class is not found?

Comment: The EntityManager is not being injected in the EventDaoImpl, although it is annotated with @PersistenceContext. It throws a NUllPointerException whenever I try to access the em field.

Comment: You are creating a new instance everytime. `EventDaoImpl` should be defined as a bean. Are u using Spring?

Comment: No, I'm not using any particular framework. I didn't realise you couldn't just new up beans. I'm completely new to this. How would you go about getting access to the object then?

Comment: Post error please, @sidgate I guess he is using EJB.

Comment: The error is a simple NullPointerException that occurs when I try to access the entityManager intstance. It seems the problem was I was newing up the class, when I should have been doing as suggested by Mike. I'm now getting a different error, but that's one I can deal with. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EventDaoImpl edi = new EventDaoImpl();
```

should be:

```
@Inject
EventDaoImpl edi;
```

or:

```
@EJB
EventDaoImpl edi;
```

This is becuase you have annotated the EventDaoImpl as a stateless bean. So you have to inject it as a bean